# how to use query where with inner join code igniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$data = array(
        'vlc.*',
        'sysinfo_cluster.*'
);

$this->db->select($data);
$this->db->from('vlc');
$this->db->join('sysinfo_cluster','vlc.DATE=sysinfo_cluster.DATE','inner');
```

i need to add where query like where vlc.CLUSTER_CHANNEL="padang"
here my model script

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
        $this->db->select('vlc.*,sysinfo_cluster.*')
                 ->from('vlc')
                 ->join('sysinfo_cluster','vlc.DATE=sysinfo_cluster.DATE','inner')
                 ->where('vlc.CLUSTER_CHANNEL','padang');
        $query  = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        print_r($result);
```